# encoding a field within a gridview

Tags: html, vb.net, gridview, encoding

I have some of these events in my gridview custom coded. But the real issue here is that I store a previous record, that is, the record that was being changed, or the old.value and I store it in another column. So when the user enters say "< newValue >"  without the quotes, the aspx validator rejects the input as dangerous.

I can disable the validation, and html encode the value as it gets written to the db, but when I display the value back in the gridview in the "Previous Value" column it appears like this...
&lt Neutral &gt semi-colons missing because this site decodes.

How I can encode and decode inline in ASPX?

How can I encode this template field that is getting entered into a gridview?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lang_String") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I would like to allow certain html characters to be entered into this field only without turning off validation for the entire site.

I do need this to apply to the entire column.

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workable solution to solve this issue. In the code behind, enter the following to call a function to process the html encoding....

```
<Columns> 
<asp:TemplateField> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
      <asp:Label ..... Text='<%# DecodeIT(Eval("FirstName").ToString())%>' /> // for "decoding" 
 </ItemTemplate> 
 <EditTemplate> 
      <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" /> // for "encoding"
```

Here is the function...

```
Private Function DecodeIT(firstName As String) As String
Return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(firstName)
End Function
```

Most other soltions suggested disabling Validation on the Page directive or in the web.config, which is NOT the best practice to solve this issue.

Using a function such as this, is the best way.